# Consulta a tabla Postgres sobre campo que almacena estructura JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Tengo una tabla de nombre *TraceabilidadAplicacion* y en ella un campo de nombre *Request* que guarda estructuras de tipo Json (todas las estructuras no son idénticas), entonces necesito construir una query donde el campo *Action* sea igual a un parámetro que le paso y una propiedad del JSON sea igual a otro parámetro.

Algo así:

```
SELECT  * FROM  “TraceabilityApp”  WHERE Action = 'action_bearer' AND  código_que_nesecito
```

Este es el json:

```json
{"Card":"1010000008551848","RechargeValue":10000,"ClientEmail":"federico.bayer@sophossolutions.com","ClientType":1,"ClientId":"1002216001","ClientName":"Federico","ClientLastName":"Bayer","ClientPhone":"3042454941","VerificationCode":"206384"}
```

He probado con varias consultas y no me ha funcionado por diferentes errores, ahora lo que no estoy seguro es si se debe a que todas las estructuras json no son iguales pero por lo menos donde el campo *Action* es igual a action_bearer si la estructura es siempre la misma:

```
SELECT * FROM "TraceabilityApp" WHERE Action = 'action_bearer' AND   "Request"->>'ClientType' = '1';

SELECT * FROM "TraceabilityApp" WHERE Action = 'action_bearer' AND     jsonb_extract_path_text("Request", 'ClientType') = '1' ;

SELECT * FROM "TraceabilityApp" WHERE Action = 'action_bearer' AND    ("Request"->>'ClientType')::integer = 1 

SELECT * FROM "TraceabilityApp" WHERE Action = 'action_bearer' AND    ("Request"->'request'->>' ClientType ') = '1';
```

Comment: La primera y tercera  senetencias debieran funcionar y si no tiene la estructucta similar o el campo que estas estas buscando, en este caso `ClientType` no pasa nada, lo que no te devuelve resultado para la fila que no lo tenga

Comment: La primera consulta  :  SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: el operador no existe: text ->> unknown
  Hint: Ningún operador coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversión explícita de tipos.
  Position: 83

Comment: La tercera consulta; SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: el operador no existe: text ->> unknown
  Hint: Ningún operador coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversión explícita de tipos.
  Position: 83

Comment: Entonces no es json tu columna, debes castearlo a json, te comento en la respuesta abajo sobre como hacerlo

Comment: Estas preguntas deben incluir la definición de la tabla para que todos sepan con qué tipos de dato estás trabajando. Como puede verse en los comentarios y la respuesta, estás poniendo a la gente a suponer. PD. No indicas tampoco versión de postgresql y hacer el cast a JSON puede ser caro dependiendo de lo que estés haciendo... puede que estés desaprovechando características de PostgreSQL si estás en una versión reciente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

segun tu error es un tema de tipo de datos:

```
ERROR: el operador no existe: text ->> unknown Hint: Ningún operador coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos
```

Debes castear la columna a `JSON`

```sql
SELECT * FROM "TraceabilityApp" WHERE Action = 'action_bearer' AND   "Request"::JSON->>'ClientType' = '1';
```